# Why am I not seeing the nmap scan results in the Wireshark log?

Tags: wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers, nmap

I used the command `nmap -sT localhost` to scan the ports on my computer and used Wireshark to view the log file of the packets exchanged between my computer and other network devices during the time that the scan was running. However, I'm not seeing any information related to the nmap scan in the Wireshark log.

For example:
The nmap scan showed that port 993 on localhost was open, but the log file does not show any interaction with port 993 on my machine.

Can someone please explain why this is? 

Also, I'm new to using nmap and Wireshark, so if there's any info that you think will help me better understand the port scanning process, please share.

Comment: If there's a programming component, please share it. Otherwise, please post this question to Super User or Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are trying to find only ACK segments. Maybe try a filter in Wireshark such as `tcp.flags.ack==1`. Or, you could be broader and not just do -sT. -sT is very specific, and may not get picked up. -sS is practically the same thing; its SYN. But it seems as if you want to just find ports open. You could try `nmap -A localhost` which is much better. But if you only want ACK, filtering in Wireshark would be the way to go it seems to me. You could also try `tcp.flags.ack==1 && tcp.flags.syn==0` to not get SYN packets too, only ACK. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

> The nmap scan showed that port 993 on localhost was open, but the log file does >not show any interaction with port 993 on my machine.
>
> Can someone please explain why this is?

My guess is that this has to do with the interface on which you're monitoring. In Wireshark-->Options you can select a capture interface.

- If you're scanning localhost and only want to see local traffic (such as the results of your nmap localhost port scan) then you should select the **loopback** interface in Wireshark.
- If you only want to see external traffic, you can select another Ethernet interface. (This is probably what's currently selected.)
- If you want to see both local and external traffic (which I think is what you're asking for), you can select **any** for the choice of interface in Wireshark.

> Also, I'm new to using nmap and Wireshark, so if there's any info that you think >will help me better understand the port scanning process, please share.

The method of port scanning you are using (`-sT`) is called a TCP Connect Scan. Here's nmap's write-up of it: https://nmap.org/book/scan-methods-connect-scan.html